# AWS Dynamodb connection reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect to Dynamodb using federated login. I created the dynamodb with sample table.When I try to access the table using aws cli, I was able to access the tables.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --profile default
```

When I tried to call using a java class I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: 
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
```

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: `Connection reset` normally means there was a network error. Does it always return that result?

Comment: Yes, when I connect through java, it always give the error.

Comment: Got this resolved, this is due to the proxy server, when provided with proxy credentials it worked fine.